# Typescript required param if other param = true

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript function with some params like that

```
myFunction(allData: Array<any>, selectedItems: Array<any>, onlyValues: boolean = false, values: Array<any>) {
    console.log(allData);
    console.log(selectedData);
    console.log(onlyValues);
    console.log(values);
}
```

If `onlyValues` is set to `true`, I want `values` to be required, else, I don't need `values`

How to do this please

Comment: You can provide [multiple signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) for the function. TypeScript will check how the function is called but in its body you still need to check the value of `onlyValues` and `values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with a guarded type:

```
type Values = {onlyValues: true, values: Array<any>} | {onlyValues: false}
```

Then you would pass `(allData: Array<any>, selectedItems: Array<any>, v: Values)` to the function.

You can try this [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM5QLxQN4HsB2CI8yaAXFMAE4oA0UAboiqhQIJVVwgA8c+IAHwBfKAB8cBIiRYUAZolQRhAKBVyk+AMbAAlgShyAFIgQAROMDjtO3PgMH0lCCDogATAJLAIAW1ZQHFy8-EL0DBQyaACUOCpQCVBaBKi4LgB0CLgA5kYM6VLEzGhQAPyM6Uyk6BT5hVGo0Sqq6kYA2gC69J30eIRF1RTUdIzFAW0A5O6WcBP0AIwdwk1AA).

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitely define a value for a parameter in a type, in this case `onlyValues` which can, in the first case only be true, in the second case only be false.

```
type Props = {
  allData: Array<any>, selectedItems: Array<any>, onlyValues: true, values: Array<any>
}

type PropsWithoutValues = {
  allData: Array<any>, selectedItems: Array<any>, onlyValues: false
}

function myFunction(props: Props | PropsWithoutValues) {
    console.log(props.allData);
    console.log(props.selectedItems);
    console.log(props.onlyValues);
    if (props.onlyValues) {
      console.log(props.values);
    }
}
```

You can try this code in the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSgQwBtCARfYfALigEE458QAefAOxAD4AaKZCQiAGNgEACYBJEQFtk1Og2ZtOPBK0IgAakQCuEWVGBxdPAG469c+oxbsO2AL7ZsoSLEQoA6gEtgACwTawFqEuqgYOHhEpORUtFaKtjx8AsJikhAylgo2ylCq6sGh1ABmRHwOTsXarMJeqlDFCHBS5OkyAGJNAMoQ+HCCvl1g+IJ6NKyiXYJIegAUYO768EioAD5uK95+AUHmyACUWLh4UNOsyAgCAHSECADm84tXUWQU+wDcx3hnF9e3DwsVldkkIRBJpAdPidTqpfhAbvdHkD8po9h8vlAvMUoEiUFcUYU9IcItCYedLvD-rjkFczCEiVCTo5HNhGs1WhDOnAen0BkMRmMJlMZshZpgXjFqABtAC6SX4oLSEOlcryalR9P0pUIfHs+1ZTRawDayC5PP6g2Go2Q40m00govFxFesVl8pSYJNKpU6sJ+kMxigdKKUClAHJgxAAIxhngAJhleuwQA).

Comment: While this answer _could_ be a solution to the OP's problem, it changes the question and introduces the bad habit that plagues the JavaScript ecosystem to cram many (possibly unrelated) values into a large "properties" or "config" object that does not have any semantic.

Comment: plagues - word of the day

Answer (score 1):

You can use function overloading to provide multiple signatures for the function:

```js
function myFunction(allData: Array<any>, selectedItems: Array<any>, onlyValues: true, values: Array<any>): void
function myFunction(allData: Array<any>, selectedItems: Array<any>, onlyValues: false): void
function myFunction(allData: Array<any>, selectedItems: Array<any>, onlyValues: boolean, values?: Array<any>): void {
    if (onlyValues) {
        // At runtime, `values` should be present but you cannot rely on that
        // Check for its presence and be prepared to handle the case when it misses
        console.log(values);
    }

    console.log(allData);
    console.log(selectedItems);
    console.log(onlyValues);
}

myFunction([1, 2, 3], [1, 3], true);                 // error, when `values` is not present, `onlyValues` must be false
myFunction([1, 2, 3], [1, 3], true, ['a', 'b']);     // OK, `onlyValues` === true, `value` is present
myFunction([1, 2, 3], [1, 3], false);                // OK, `onlyValues` === false, `value` is not present
myFunction([1, 2, 3], [1, 3], false, ['a', 'b']);    // error, `onlyValues` === false, `value` must not be present
```

Check it online on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmAFAQwBtCARfKfALkQEEAnO-VAHnzFQD4AaRAZwFNC-aPwAmASSj9kvavUYs2nHgkKoAakRD9ZiKHW08Ablp1yGTVuw4BKakbgxRAKFCRYCFBiwe8RUuRUtBaK1jwCQiISUjLmClbKiKoaprrARAJ2iA5Orj44XpjuOATEZBRxlkrcfILCUtHSuvJVYUlgapqE2roARnBwQmzGqQD8laGcWTmiiADezohLiDDAiLjJXT0284vL+wD0B4gABibdOid8ABZwIISzvfyIAA50OvxgUIi9IN+od0QEDYYDg33eanaemu5D2+yWR0QAGFrsIANaIYBwOgrKC8V7vASQZ5sR7PN78F74d6zKBwRAwsCiITQ57AgSIADuqKQMG+MHxoKgcPhEAQvEG-AAdIQ4ABzXDnbYAbhFAF9nCKxWAJUIZfLSgEKDZVfttbrpbKFRF6mJJE0TVrxZL9QrNqlHRrnGgitgELgANoARh4ACYeABmAC6PGDkZjegM-BN8NTqcR-AY2J43M+pyVlxWgrBBI+Xx4J3dF14V2QIF43yemIy-G93mK-rjiHDiGjsZDvYT+kMiADAHJ8GOeGPemOoynDscAPIAaQrVZ6VwAvDvEyOzqYrgLS0ThT78p2Bz2+6OBzf0oRMsq0y-EIjV+uOilq9vdw+BBWBZHsW3wUqeba+r4gZXvG-awc2j78LGE5TogM5zguCLHJmdDZqcG6FjuW4IQB+aHig9bfEKPzkoSnxQEAA).